# Cloud Run Authenticating end-users of a CLI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

We are porting an existing API to Cloud Run and would like to make use of the built in IAM authentication features. This means generating a signed JWT for use as an Authorization Bearer token. There is [documentation that describes how to do this](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/end-users) for iOS, Android, and Web. However, it's not clear what the best approach for a CLI running on a user's local machine is.

What we have done in the past is use a Google user's local credentials to authorize with the API (using Default Application Credentials), but it's not clear to me how to generate the appropriate `access_id` from within Go. This only seems possible with a Service Account type. Not a Authorized User type. The only way I've been able to obtain a valid `access_id` is by using the gcloud command.

```
gcloud config config-helper --format json
```

Other than shelling out to the above command, is there a more appropriate method for generating user credentials in a CLI for authorizing with a Cloud Run hosted service?

Comment: Can you link to "Authorized User" type you mentioned in the question. I don't quite understand what it means.

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Run uses Oauth 2.0 (OIDC) Identity Tokens for authorization. This is supported for both user accounts and service accounts. Where you would have used an OAuth Access Token in the `authorization: bearer token` header, use the Identity Token.

To experiment, you can generate Identity Tokens with this command:

```
gcloud auth print-identity-token
```

With Cloud Run you will need to specify the `audience` value for the Identity Token. Details in the links below.

Here are some additional links to help you get started:

**Articles that I wrote on Cloud Run Identity:**

[Google Cloud Run - Identity](https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-run-identity/)

[Google Cloud – Go – Identity Based Access Control](https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-go-identity-based-access-control/)

**Google Cloud Run Documents:**

[Google Cloud Run Service Identity](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/service-identity)

[Google Cloud Run Authenticating end users](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/end-users)

Comment: I updated my answer with two documents that I wrote on Cloud Run Identity.

Comment: You mentioned Cloud Run supports both user accounts and service accounts.  But looking at the original question around using IAM and the article who refers to 'internal' users - the only option seems to be going the IAP route?

Comment: @JanKrynauw - I am not sure what you mean by **IAP route**. Access is controlled by IAM no matter the path the request arrives from. A Cloud Run service is either public, VPC private via a connector, or authorized by OIDC identity tokens.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the 'client' here is a human user (not service account) of the CLI.  And from your above link on Authenticating end users they differentiate between External (using Cloud Identity, which is not IAM, or Firebase) users and Internal (using IAP, Identity Aware Proxy, which is using IAM under the hood) users.  Why refer internal users to IAP?

Comment: @JanKrynauw - Please create a new question. You have a misunderstanding of what identities are in Google Cloud. That deserves a new post.

Comment: no problem will do.  found a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58072361/google-cloud-auth-for-internal-cli-using-cloud-run